# How to block annoying twitter search widget

Tags: firefox, blocking, twitter, widgets

[this](http://twitter.com/goodies/widget_search) twitter search widget is popping up all around the internet. the animation is annoying me. newspapers think they are cool when they put this twitter widget next to their articles, but the animation distracts me from reading the article. it is just as bad as those damn flashing flash banners, just without the sound.

is there a way to disable/block those widgets? stopping the animation would be enough.

i am using firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know if this would work, but is worth a try: [Adblock Plus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1865/) addon for Firefox?

Perhaps find the source script and add it to the block list in Adblock Plus...

*Also make sure that you have all popups disabled...*

Comment: use the filter `##div.twtr-doc`. see http://adblockplus.org/en/filters

Answer (score 3):

Install [GreaseMonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/748/) and install [this script](http://tom.hsc.be/meta/remove.widget.user.js) that I wrote for you, here is [the source](http://tom.hsc.be/meta/remove.widget.user.txt):

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name          Remove the Twitter Widget.
// @description   This will remove the Twitter Widget, everywhere.
// ==/UserScript==

(function(){
  var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.textContent = "(" + twremoval.toString() + ")();";
  document.body.appendChild(script);

  function twremoval() {
    $(function() {
      $("div.twtr-doc").remove();
    });
  }
})();
```

Comment: thanks, works like a charm. please include the source code in your answer, just in case your server goes down.