# How to block annoying Google RSS feed widget

Tags: firefox, blocking, widgets

[This](http://www.google.com/uds/solutions/wizards/dynamicfeed.html) annoying Google RSS feed widget is just as annoying as [this](https://superuser.com/questions/195844/how-to-block-annoying-twitter-search-widget) annoying Twitter search widget. How can I block it? I'm using Firefox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

install [adblock plus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1865/).

add filter `##div.gfg-root` and `##div.gfg-horizontal-root`.